# How do I split a list based on index in C#?

Tags: c#, list, split

I have a list with around 190 elements in it for now. How can I split the list into smaller lists with a max of 50 elements in each list?

The result could be lists of 50, 50, 50 and 40 elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming you mean `List<T>`, you can use the [`GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) method repeatedly. Heck, you could do this with LINQ:

```
var lists = Enumerable.Range(0, (list.Count + size - 1) / size)
      .Select(index => list.GetRange(index * size,
                                     Math.Min(size, list.Count - index * size)))
      .ToList();
```

Or you could just use a loop, of course:

```
public static List<List<T>> Split(List<T> source, int size)
{
    // TODO: Validate that size is >= 1
    // TODO: Prepopulate with the right capacity
    List<List<T>> ret = new List<List<T>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i += size)
    {
        ret.Add(source.GetRange(i, Math.Min(size, source.Count - i)));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This is somewhat more efficient than using `GroupBy`, although it's limited to `List<T>` as an input.

We have another implementation using `IEnumerable<T>` in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) in [Batch.cs](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs).

Comment: Historical : I never ever saw Jon, not even a splitsecond, on -1.  I will ask in his place : would the minus voter care to elaborate? --> and ofcourse he beat me to that one :-)

Comment: @Jon, I didn't downvote but I think it was due to the late example.

Comment: -1 for Leaving half answer with "coming soon" doesnt make sense.

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar: `GetRange` is really the heart of it though... the rest is pretty trivial, and that shows the efficient way of creating one list from another. I wanted to make *that* information available while creating the sample code. Of course, I've now expanded the answer with two examples, and a link to another implementation which is still more efficient than using GroupBy...

Comment: +1 for informative.  Another downvoter however, even after the examples as far as I can see.  That minus vote I would like seen explained (just out of my curiosity)

Comment: Thanks Jon. The foreach seems to be the most simple and clean answer.

Comment: Why would you post a one liner about "sample coming"? What's the benefit of that?

Comment: @MikeEast: Because `GetRange` was the most important part, in my view.  It's a simple and efficient way of getting part of a list, as another list. Once you know about it, using it is easy.

Comment: Note that for `size == 0`, this function will enter infinite loop.

Comment: @Tomer: I've added a validation TODO in there.

Answer (score 11):

You could use LINQ:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 190);
var sublists = list
    .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 50)
    .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but Jon's foreach is just cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted a recursive approach. Just to see what it would look like.

```
List<List<T>> SplitIntoChunks<T>(IEnumerable<T> originalList, int chunkSize)
{
    if(originalList.Take(1).Count() == 0)
    {
        return new List<List<T>>();
    }

    var chunks = new List<List<T>> {originalList.Take(chunkSize).ToList()};
    chunks.AddRange(SplitIntoChunks(originalList.Skip(chunkSize), chunkSize));
    return chunks;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1,190));
var page_size = 50;
var max_pages = 1 + list.Count() / page_size;

for(int page = 1; page <= max_pages; page++) {
  var chunk = list.Skip(page_size * (page-1)).Take(page_size);
  // do whatever
}
```